# Perturbation theory amongst supersymmetry transformations of perturbative ground states

Tags: supersymmetry, perturbation-theory, instantons

Consider a supersymmetric one dimensional sigma-model whose target is a Riemannian manifold $M$. Moreover, assume there is a Morse function $h$ on $M$. In Hori, Kentaro, Cumrun Vafa, Sheldon Katz, Albrecht Klemm, Rahul Pandharipande, Richard Thomas, Ravi Vakil, and Eric Zaslow. Mirror Symmetry. Clay Mathematics Monographs 1. American Mathematical Society and Clay Mathematics Institute, 2003, it is explained how for every critical point $p\in\text{Crit}\,h$ there is a perturbative ground state $|p\rangle$, meaning a ground built by doing perturbation theory in $\lambda^{-1/2}$ of the operator
$$H=\frac{1}{2}\Delta+\frac{\lambda^2}{2}g^{ab}\partial_ah\partial_bh+\frac{\lambda}{2}[\Psi^a,\bar{\Psi}^b]\nabla_a\nabla_bh=\lambda\sum_{a=1}^n\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}^a}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}c_a^2(\tilde{x}^a)^2+\frac{1}{2}[\Psi^a,\bar{\Psi}_a]c_a\right)+\mathcal{O}(\lambda^{1/2}),$$
obtained by choosing Riemann normal coordinates $x$ around $p$ which also diagonalize the Hessian of $h$ and rescaling them to $\tilde{x}=\lambda^{1/2}x$.

They then later state that it is possible that these are however not true ground states. To see this, they mention that in general $Q|p\rangle\neq 0$. Instead,
$$Q|p\rangle=\sum_{q\in \text{Crit}\,h}|q\rangle\langle q|Q|p\rangle+|\phi_p\rangle,$$
where $|\phi_p\rangle$ is orthogonal to all perturbative ground states. They mention that in this expansion, $|\phi_p\rangle$ is smaller than the other terms by powers of $\lambda^{-1}$. I am however failing to see why this should be the case. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!